# Add new column count in Laravel controller

Tags: sql, laravel

I am trying to add a new column total_count that contains the count of all rows in sample for pagination.

Is there a way to select count(*) as total_count in $sample itself instead of *$total_count = $sample->count()*

```
     $var1 = $request->xyz;
     $var2 = $request->abc;
     $take = $request->take;
     $skip = $request->skip;
    
     $sample = DB::table('table_name')
                       ->where('column_name1', $var1)
                       ->where('column_name2', $var2)
                       ->offset($skip)->limit($take)
                       ->get();
    
     $total_count = $sample->count();
        
     $encrypted = AESEncrypt($sample);
     return json_encode($encrypted);
```

OR can I write something like this

```
 $sample = DB::table('table_name')
                       ->select('table_name.*', DB::raw('COUNT(column_name) as total_count'))
                       ->where('column_name1', $var1)
                       ->where('column_name2', $var2)
                       ->offset($skip)->limit($take)
                       ->get();
```

Comment: "_But I am getting error_" What _is_ the error you get?

Comment: @brombeer I have edited the question. Please check

Comment: To Get Total Count `$total_count = count($sample);`
But Where You Want Use This Variable `$total_count` ?

Comment: @HichamAITTALGHALIT I want to return that variable. So can I write it inside $sample?

Comment: `$sample` is objects collection !!! 
you can return data and get the count whenn you receive response api (from front)

Answer (score 1):

You directly call

```
->paginate(10)
```

at the end of your query like:

```
$sample = DB::table('table_name')
                   ->where('column_name1', $var1)
                   ->where('column_name2', $var2)
                   ->paginate(10);
```

Laravel itself handles all count pages etc.

You can use below code for total count of your table. If you need special where case then you should it too.

```
ModelName::count();
```

Or you can use

```
DB::table('table_name')->count();
```

You can read [more in here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination)

Comment: Hi @gguney, I want a new column named total_count in the DB.

Comment: @smrithi In the database? You use [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations) to add/remove/alter columns in your database

Comment: @brombeer we are using kendo ui for pagination. kendo sees at the total_count column in the the table. So I have to add this field in the data passed

Comment: Do you want to add to the table or do you want to get all the records count in the table?

Comment: You dont need to add this column to the table. You have to generate this value dynamically when you querying all the result

Comment: I doubt that a UI framework (or whatever kendo UI is) has access to your DB. If you want to do something with your `$total_count` you should include it in the JSON response you return. Right now you only calculate the count but do nothing with it

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to include the fact that you need that counter for Kendo UI in your question, so people have all the relevant information in one place. Not everyone reads this answer or it might get removed so the info will be lost. Also, "discussion" should take place at your question, not this answer

Comment: @brombeer Is there a way to write it as - select count(*) as total_count here?

Comment: You can  use your query and send it to your frontend. Or DB::table('table_name')->count() or use your model as Model::count();

Comment: @gguney yes how to send this in frontend?

Comment: If you are using blade view you can return view from your controller and add 2. Parameter as key value array, or if you are using jsom then again use key value pair array as return, but it is another question

Comment: @gguney can I add this query line inside $sample  _->select('table_name.*', DB::raw('COUNT(column_name) as total_count'))_

Comment: I edited my answer you can check there. I answered your question completely.